# How estimate cost and gamma with libsvm using 5-fold cross validation

Tags: matlab

```
data = L_f(org,:); % input data to the SVR model  
label =dmos(org); % output of the SVR model   

% the (cost, gamma) parameters for the SVR learning
% the optimal parameters we found for the 3 proposed models on the   
% databases.
% (cost, gamma)  = (65536, 2) for LIVE M1  
% (cost, gamma)  = (1024,   8) for LIVE M2  
% (cost, gamma)  = (16384, 2) for LIVE M3  
% (cost, gamma)  = (32768, 4) for CSIQ M1      
% (cost, gamma)  = (65536, 2) for CSIQ M2  
% (cost, gamma)  = (16384, 2) for CSIQ M3
% (cost, gamma)  = (2048 ,16) for TID2008 M1  
% (cost, gamma)  = (2048,   8) for TID2008 M2  
% (cost, gamma)  = (128,   16) for TID2008 M3  
cost =0.0313 ;
gamma = 3.0518e-05;  
c_str = sprintf('%f',cost);  
g_str = sprintf('%.2f',gamma);     
libsvm_options = ['-s 3 -t 2 -g ',g_str,' -c ',c_str];

spear_results = zeros(N,1);  
% Training and Test procedure  
for i = 1:N  
    % get the index of the distorted image from the index of the reference  
    % image for the traning set and the test set. 
  train = ismember(ref_ind_live,C(i,:)); 
 test = ~train;  

 model = svmtrain(label(train),data(train,:),libsvm_options);  
   [predict_score, ~, ~] = svmpredict(label(test), data(test,:), model);      
   spear_results(i) = corr(predict_score, label(test),'type','Spearman');
 end  
 % median Spearman Coefficient (SRC) performance 
 spear_median = median(spear_results);  
spear_std = std(spear_results,0);
```

I am writing a program for assessing image quality. In previous articles, authors have used  Libsvm. As you can see in this code, they calculated **cost** and **gamma** separately by **5-fold cross validation** but I really don't know how they did it.
Please help me.

Comment: Please don't insert the code as a screenshot, but copy it into your question (EDIT the question, don't post it as comment). You can format it as code using the Code Sample button `{ }`. And please include more detail to the question: what exactly do you not understand? With the code and the LibSVM documentation, you should be able to find out, or not?

Comment: sorry i don't know how do it :| i registered one week ago.
 actually in the code at first it makes a cell: Libsvm_options.
later send it to Svr-train to create the regression model for Svm-predict
but they have calculated cost and gamma from before via cross-validation and dident writ its code and i really don't know how they achieved it!

Comment: Please reformat your post. If you do not know how to, you can read http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I tried all my best to edit it,sorry if it isn't so good

Comment: no one can **help** me? :(

Comment: Have you got the answer? Please share if so.